# What right click shortcuts are there?

Tags: browser, shortcuts, copy-paste, copy

When you rightclick on a link in firefox and then press E.

```
rightclick + 'E'
```

It copies the link without the extra step of having to click the "copy link" button in the menu.

Where do I see what key corresponds to what action?

Comment: Not on Firefox ...

Comment: There are many browsers and many operating systems. Please be more specific.

Comment: Your title does not correspond to the body of your question. The title can, and should, be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a GUI convention to show the key for a *menu item* by underlining it in the label. For example, in the right-click context menu from Firefox, shown below,

- Pressing <kbd>T</kbd> would *Open Link in New Tab*.
- Pressing <kbd>W</kbd> would *Open Link in New Container Tab*.
- Pressing <kbd>L</kbd> would *Copy Link*.

Examine context menus (and *other* menus, as well!) for underlined characters to find others.

[image: Right-click keys]

Comment: Browsers seem to render their own menus nowadays, but in Windows 10, in general, it may be necessary to switch on "Underline access key shortcuts in menus when they are available" - press the Windows key and start typing "underline access" to get to the setting.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, thanks, I had not noticed that option before!

Comment: As you mention a GUI convention, in recent versions of Gnome you can't get the access keys: [How to use window menu accelerators/mnemonics in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1032810) - but they do appear in Firefox on Ubuntu. I don't have a machine running macOS, so I'll stop there.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.